# Kony - Build.xml for generating .apk file

Tags: temenos-quantum

I am using Kony Visualizer Starter, as I have to integrate the process with Jenkins, and execute automation test cases on the build, I have to generate a .apk file.

When I execute `ant -file build.xml` command. I encounter following error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "com.pat.tool.keditor.konyapplication" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.ant.ui.antRunner, org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.console.profile.StorageFileEditor, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.GenTopic, org.eclipse.emf.codegen.CodeGen, org.eclipse.emf.codegen.JMerger, org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.Generator, org.eclipse.emf.importer.ecore.Ecore2GenModel, org.eclipse.emf.importer.java.Java2GenModel, org.eclipse.emf.importer.rose.Rose2GenModel, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.EclipseGenerator, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.repo2runnable, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.metadataverifier, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives.nativePackageExtractor, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher, org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool, org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaIndexer, org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core.SetupArchiver, org.eclipse.pde.build.Build, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.legacytestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.coretestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.coretestapplicationnonmain, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.nonuithreadtestapplication, org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench, org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter, org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.preview.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1474)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
```

Please note that I have created `Headless-Global.properties` file, because it was not generated by Kony Visualizer Starter.

Following are the properties set on the `Headless-Global.properties` file

```
#This file need to be copied in workspace location
#Note: Please escape '\' with '\\' in file paths (Ex: C:\\workspace\\project)

#Envirnoment details
workspace.location=

#Full Path to a jar file whose name starts with 'org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_' in eclipse plugins folder
#Example: D:\\eclipse\\plugins\\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
eclipse.equinox.path=C:\\Users\\SO-LPT-011\\eclipse\\jee-2018-12\\eclipse\\plugins\\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.200.v20180922-1751.jar

#preference details
imagemagic.home=
android.home=
run.luaapichecker=false
playbook.home=
qt.home=
palm.home=
bb10.ndk.home=
bb10.signing.keys.home =
bb10.emulator.ip=
bb10.emulator.password=
bb10.vmware.home=
```

Can I install `"com.pat.tool.keditor.konyapplication"` plugin?

Comment: Hi @mubeen, if you found my answer below helpful, would you mind marking it as the correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot** generate an installable binary -i.e. Android `.apk` nor iOS `.ipa`- using Visualizer *Starter*. Visualizer *Starter* is meant as a prototyping tool only, used for quick ideation and for UX designers.

In order to build a `.apk` file you'll need to install Visualizer *Enterprise*. All downloads are available from the [Kony release site here](https://community.kony.com/downloads). You'll have to register for a Kony developer account in order to download, but this is free of charge.

Once you have installed Visualizer Enterprise, you'll be able to build the .apk [from the Visualizer UI](https://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/visualizer/visualizer_user_guide/Default.htm#BuildAnAppForAndroid.htm) or [from the command line](https://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/visualizer/visualizer_user_guide/Default.htm#CommandLine.htm).

Comment: I asked the same question on the forum, They claim that Visualizer Starter can also generate .apk file. However, I could not generate the .apk file by their solutions either, because there was no plugin folder. I believe, you are right, but I have to explore more. But, thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: See the link: https://basecamp.kony.com/s/question/0D56A00000VD5AISA1/whats-the-build-output-path-for-kony-visualizer-application?t=1549050084120

Comment: Saw that. But they *are* telling you the same thing I am: *"In starter edition we cannot generate apk or kar file."* --Farzana Shaik 9 months ago. What they *are* saying in turn is that instead of generating an apk or ipa you can instead use the "Preview" feature. Meaning that [Visualizer Starter can publish a prototype](http://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/visualizer/viz_app_viewer/Default.htm#FunctionalPreviewStarter.htm?TocPath=Preview%2520and%2520Collaborate%2520on%2520a%2520Project|Preview%2520an%2520App%2520on%2520a%2520Device|_____1) to the Kony Cloud...

Comment: from which you can [download and even provide feedback](http://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/visualizer/viz_app_viewer/Default.htm#PreviewAppAcrossStarterAndEnterprise.htm%3FTocPath%3DPreview%2520and%2520Collaborate%2520on%2520a%2520Project%7C_____4) *as if* it were an actual installation. You can also load the prototype locally, straight from your workstation into the [Visualizer mobile app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kony.FunctionPreviewApp) installed in your mobile device.